# CSS: centering a div in a nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm having weird problems centering a div within another div. I was trying to make a nav bar, here is the html:

```
 <body>
    <div class="nav">
         <div class="navbar">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Our Future</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="right">Join us</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="right">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
```

And the corresponding css:

```
.nav{
 width:100%;
 }
.navbar {
 width:75%;
 height:50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:#E64888;   
 position:fixed;
}
```

so this didn't work in any of my browsers-chrome,firefox,ie...The bar is just sitting on the very left side. I have also tried the "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" method, but still didn't work. This is really annoying, cuz I cant figure what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the primary `nav ul` to be centered, you need to set it's parent (in this case `html` and `body`) to have width. Otherwise, you have to handle the dimensions and the layout (`display`) type on the `li`s and the `list-style-type` on the `ul li` elements (so you don't see the dots).

There's also a padding on the `ul` (which is what spaces the `li`s to the right when it's a normal list) that you have to deal with, or it will appear to far to the right (and "uncentered").

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar ul {
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #E64888;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/97B52/

Answer (score 0):

Try: (As far as I understood your question):

```
.nav li {list-style: none; display: inline-block; }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/kjHrd/3/)

Comment: If you look, it's not actually centered in either the `ul` or the `li`s within the `ul`.